# How to hook into the close event of IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I want to perform some clean-up in my ASP.NET web application when the user closes the IE window or the tab page in which the page is open.

I was looking at the unload event of the "body" element, however the unload event also gets fired when you click the Refresh button in IE or change the URL by typing in the address bar.

Any ideas on which event to catch to trap IE window (6.0 and 7.0) and Tab closing?

Answer (score 1):

use InProc sessions, and the `Session_End` event in global.ascx to do your cleanup. javascript is too unreliable for this.

Comment: right. i'd implement some sort of server side monitor thread then, that checks a timestamp of last request per session every X mins, and do your housekeeping in it. you could even add an AJAX background postback to your page if you really want to check if a browser is still open, but again, its not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will be unreliable/quite restricting on this for security reasons.  It really depends what you are trying to do, if you are trying to fire some code on the clients machine then this is going to be difficult/impossible (which is a good thing, I don't really want websites I don't trust messing with my browser on one of it's most core features, closing a window).

If you want to run some server side scripts to flag the user as gone, again, hard/impossible, as Jasper mentioned global.ascx will go some way as to helping you, but otherwise you will have to have timers and events fired on 'expired' users.